# Phonegap plugin:retrive user profile, email and gmail

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am new in `Phonegap` development. In my current project, i want to get user profile name, gmail and email address. I know how to retrieve these information in native `Android`. By using which plugin, i can get these information in `Phonegap`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this plugin will full fill your needs (https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin).
It will give the following data

1.Your unique Device ID

2.Phone Number (if it is stored in your SIM card)

3.Country ISO of your phone network provider

4.Name of your network provider

5.Your SIM Card Serial number

6.Country ISO of your SIM card
7.Name of your SIM card mobile operator

8.E-mail/Phone number used by apps listed in your Settings > Accounts & Sync list

Here is sample code

```
var deviceInfo = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/DeviceInformation");
deviceInfo.get(function(result) {
      //fetch the device data
        console.log("result = " + result);
    }, function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

Comment: yeah that's my desired plugin.Now, i am in little bit problem with retrieving json object. Using following code `deviceInfo.get(function(result) {
        var jsonData = result;
        var objData = JSON.parse("'"+jsonData+"'");
        navigator.notification.alert(
                        "result = " + objData.deviceID,`.Would you help me in this regard?

Comment: in logcat it shows `result = {account0Name:'my_email_address', account0Type:'account_type',....,deviceID:'device_ID',....`

Comment: try this `var t=JSON.parse(result); alert (t['name'])`

Comment: change `alert (t['name'])` to `alert (t['deviceID'])`

Comment: @ArnoldRoa when  the time i used it its working fine ,don't know the current status of that plugin